# Show full calendar on Calendar item in Notification Center on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, calendar, macos-catalina

Before Catalina, I used the iCal widget in the Dashboard as a way to quickly view the calendar. But Apple removed it all together now. 
So I come to use the Calendar item in Notification Center. Currently, it only shows the upcoming events, not the calendar itself. Is there any way to change it? 
Or if there is some way to quickly show a calendar, please do tell me.

How it is:
[image: Calendar item in Notification Center]

How I want it to show:
[image: A proper calendar]

Comment: I've never seen the 2nd type, only the 1st. Are you sure it wasn't a 3rd party add-in?

Comment: The 2nd picture is a screenshot from the Calendar app itself. Just not the one appears in the Notification Center. If it can show the calendar along with the month's events, it would be nice. Otherwise, something to show a calendar quickly should be fine too. 
Should I edit the answer to make it clearer?

Comment: oh, actually maybe not. I had misread. I'm still on Mojave [old Mac Pros here] so had forgotten Dashboard is now gone. I just looked at Notification Centre Widgets in the App Store… there's a calendar widget called Fantastical… at the absolutely jaw-dropping price of £48.99 At that price it should be able to clean the car & do the washing up too ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Mini Calendar - once installed & launched, it becomes an option to add in Notification Center:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mini-calendar/id1088779979?mt=12

You can also disable the menu icon etc..

[mini calendar in Notification Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEa3T.png)

Answer (score 6):

On macOS Big Sur, the new design of the Up Next widget can now show a full calendar on M size.

Go to Notification Center by clicking on the Day time button on the Menu bar, click Edit Widgets and choose Up Next, choose size M and click the + icon. [image]

Comment: What about Monterey? A size M widget no longer seems to display a full month (instead it shows today and tomorrow for me).

Comment: Monterey now has an entire Widget just showing the calendar alone. It's called "Month" and is in the Calendar section.